# TSQL "IF @@Rowcount > 0" analog in Sqlite?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlite

I have t-sql insert query to table [foo] (bar_id int primary key autoincrement, bar_name varchar) with text:

```
INSERT INTO foo(bar_name)
VALUES (@bar_name_new);
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    SELECT bar_id, bar_name
    FROM foo
    WHERE bar_id = scope_identity();
```

A trigger can modify bar_name field after insert. That's why I need to refresh "bar_name" field.
Now I need to do the same at sqlite db. I've wrote this:

```
INSERT INTO foo(bar_name)
VALUES (@bar_name_new);

 SELECT bar_id, bar_name
 FROM foo
 WHERE bar_id = (SELECT last_insert_rowid());
```

I can check number of changes in db calling sqlite changes() function. And I know about case statement in sqlite. But how can I tell sqlite that there is no need to do select when changes() returns 0?

Comment: Can't you just slap `AND changes() > 0` to the end of the select?

Answer (score 2):

SQLite's flavor of SQL doesn't have the branch and loop constructs that T-SQL has.  Control-flow logic is exercised in the host language.

In your case, you want the [sqlite3_changes](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html) function.  You're going to need it anyway, to decide whether there are any rows to retrieve.  Although, as a matter of ease and efficiency, you might as well just execute the query `where changes() > 0` if (as I suspect) the query planner is smart enough to return instantly.